# Find nearest polygons of a multi-line string

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-dwithin

I am trying to find the nearerst (100-200 meters) parcels of the green line. Given The photo below, they database should return 12 records. I am using [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) postgis function. Is this the correct way?

```
FROM
gis_streets as gs --green line
left join "parcel" as p --black polygons
on ST_DWithin(gs.geom,p."parcel_geometry",3000)
```

[image]

Comment: it would depend on what you mean by "nearerst"? with in 3000 units of your line may or may not be close

Comment: Nearest i mean 100-200 meters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the nearest is actually a different problem that what you're showing. Here you try to find all the polygons at 3000 units or closer than your line.

If you want all the polygons which are closer than 200 meters, you just have to modify the parameter in ST_DWithin (I assume your data is projected in meter):

```
FROM
gis_streets as gs --green line
left join "parcel" as p --black polygons
on ST_DWithin(gs.geom, p."parcel_geometry", 200)
ORDER BY gs.geom <-> p."parcel_geometry";
```

I added the fact that the results are sorted by the closest first.

If you want the 12 closest polygon, this is different, you can do it like that:

```
FROM
gis_streets as gs --green line
left join "parcel" as p --black polygons
ORDER BY gs.geom <-> p."parcel_geometry"
LIMIT 12;
```

Comment: for some reason units don't work for me, I even use `0.001` and a lot of records are returned `ST_DWithin(gs.geom, p."parcel_geometry", 0.001)`

Comment: you probably have your geometries not projected (in 4326, a.k.a. GPS data). Try to cast in geography instead `ST_DWithin(gs.geom::geography, p."parcel_geometry"::geography, 200)`
Geography is a special kind of geometries especially for GPS data and that is handled by a lot of postgis function. Another option is to project you data (see https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/projection.html)